# Book about a boy surviving in a forest with animal friends

Tags: identification-request

I do not remember much detail about this book my mother once read to me when I was little. What I do remember is that the protagonist was a boy surviving in a forest. He made his home out of a big tree which he hollowed out. There was a long winter. He had a bunch of animal friends, and I think one was a hawk or a falcon. I think he grew up in the woods if I remember correctly. I think he saved the forest from hunters or something.

I'm not sure; it was like 13 years ago that I heard it, but it has been on my mind. Any suggestions would help. I very vaguely remember the book cover; if I were to see it again, I could tell that it was the book.

Comment: Are you sure it was only one boy? Also could you describe the cover at all?

Comment: Edgar Rice Burroughs *Tarzan* series? :)

Answer (score 5):

A quick Google search lead me to the book [*My Side of the Mountain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Side_of_the_Mountain) by Jean Craighead George. Could that be the book you meant?

> The book is about Sam Gribley, a 14-year-old boy who intensely dislikes living in his parents' cramped New York City apartment with his eight brothers and sisters. He decides to run away to his great-grandfather's abandoned farm in the Catskill Mountains to live in the wilderness. The reader meets Frightful, Sam's pet peregrine falcon, and The Baron, a weasel that Sam befriends. Roughly the first 80 percent of the novel is Sam's reminiscences during a snowstorm about how he came to be in a home made out of a hollowed-out tree, while the remainder of the novel is a traditional linear narrative about what happens after the snowstorm.

Comment: Welcome to Literature! I've edited in a brief excerpt from the Wikipedia page, so that it's more clear how this book matches the description in the question. With just a title and a link, it was harder to judge how good the match was; with this description, it's much easier to see things like the falcon, the hollowed-out tree, and the storm, and I've upvoted :-) See also [our site guidance](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/840/17) on writing good story-ID answers.